# rsyslog not separating for facilities

Tags: configuration, cisco, rsyslog

I will preface this with, I am a Linux newbie. I had set up a Debian Linux rsyslog server that was working, but I had to switch to Ubuntu(14.04.1 LTS) to set up rsyslog(7.4.4). I was hoping that I would be able to just copy the parts of the config over and it would work. That has not been the case.

My syslog is receiving the information, however it is just writing to the default file `/var/log/syslog`.

Here is my current config, I have edited out the items that were commented out:

```
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support

$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514

$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514

$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

$RepeatedMsgReduction on

$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog

#this was a template given to me that had worked in debian
$template Firewall,"/var/log/prd/fwlog-%$YEAR%-%$MONTH%-%$DAY%"
$template Switch,"/var/log/prd/rslog-%$YEAR%-%$MONTH%-%$DAY%"

Local7.* -?Firewall
Local4.* -?Switch
```

Is there some things that differ for rsyslog in Ubuntu vs. Debian?

Comment: I realized, with some help, that I was using a different version of rsyslog(v5) and that the templates are different.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration files differ dramatically (and annoyingly) between versions.  So trying to copy your /etc/rsyslog.conf file from one system to another probably won't work, especially if you're switching major releases.  (In this case from version 5 to version 7.)

Ubuntu IS Debian under the hood, and rsyslog is rsyslog regardless of the OS it's installed on.  The important point is to make sure you google for instructions specific to your version, or use your package manager to install the accompanying rsyslog-docs package, then read those.  In ubuntu/debian:

```
apt-get install rsyslog-docs
```